# Textures appear different in object and edit mode

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I'm a novice with this program and 3D editing so I'm not entirely sure how I would fix this. Basically, I'm trying to make a 3D model of a character from a Nintendo 64 game, so I ripped the model and texture files using a graphics plugin on an N64 emulator, however the textures didn't map to the model properly, so I'm just going in the UV editor and trying to correct it. So far the textures appear fine in edit mode, but when I go to any others some polygons are textureless. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

For reference, here is what it looks like on edit mode:

[image]

And here is what it looks like on object mode:

[image]

[Here is the project file for the model](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pUcRAe4I8A9ct990Ed8ctpp48u3a2Fbb)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. It's because some faces were overlapping. Works fine now.